# node.js data access acl permission

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, acl

Hi please can anyone help me. I want user to be able to access only what they are permitted to access.

I have been looking at several Access Control List packages. I have not made a final decision.

A restaurant which would have several levels of permission.

1. The customer can place several orders and can see what foods he has ordered
2. He can also modify the order only within a specified time period e.g. before the order is being processed.
3. The customer can only view his own order and the stage which the order is.
4. A staff can only check the order than is under his menu and state how much the order would cost and how long the order would take.
5. Another staff would be in charge of the stores and how things goes in and goes out.
6. A Staff can be in charge of a department and at the same time allow input to a menu which is under another department.

I have been looking at how I can go about putting this into Express.js and mongodb

I have looked at the following

https://github.com/optimalbits/node_acl main focus

https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-acl

But I have not got the granularity and the mix which I stated above.

The permission would be based majorly on data. It has been a little confusing as to how I can go about that.

Any help will be useful

I use mongoose as my driver

Comment: You're conflating access control with business rules.  ACLs in particular are great for describing that a user has (or hasn't) the permission to read/modify a given object.  They're not great at validating that the modification is appropriate (e..g based on the state of the object).

Comment: please how can i achieve my objective? any help or direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comments, this design has a bit of business logic that might make it not the best fit for regular ACL-type security controls.  On the surface, it seems like the easier to figure out solution would be to just implement your business rules in your Mongoose models or Controller code, depending on your preference.  That said, a key piece of doing any of this with an ACL-like approach comes down to your URL design.  For example, it's tempting to make your API such that all orders are available through `/api/orders` and maybe a person would query their own orders via `/api/orders?userId=12345`.  But that makes most ACL-based approaches fail.  Instead you have to think about the API in terms of the hierarchy as you want it secured (regardless of if all orders are stored in the Orders Mongoose model, and persist in the orders collection).

So using your first requirement as an example

> The customer can place several orders and can see what foods he has ordered

The focus here is that you are securing things by the customer 'owner' of the orders, so to secure it that way you need to setup your route that way, eg (assuming you're using the first middleware you asked about):

```
app.post('/api/customer/:customerId/orders', acl.middleware(), (req, res, next) => { 
  const order = new Order(req.body); // TODO: whitelist what info you take in here
  order.customerId = req.user.id; // assuming you have a logged-in user that does this
  order.save(e => {
    if (e) return next(e);
    return res.status(201).send(order);
  });  
});
```

To support this, you'd register your ACL info as such:

```
acl.allow('12345', '/api/customer/12345/orders', ['post']);
```

Minimally, you'd do that.  You would likely provide more options such as 'get', etc. As you can guess, this means that you'll need to register permissions for individual users whenever you create them (to support the concept of 'ownership').

For your second requirement,

> He can also modify the order only within a specified time period e.g. before the order is being processed.

Despite what I said before, you could arguably do this in an ACL if you really wanted to.  For example, you could make the URL account for the status, like '/api/customers/12345/orders/modifiable/6789', but that becomes hard to maintain in my experience.  You're better off putting that logic in the controller or the Mongoose logic.  It's probably simpler to do it in the controller, unless you plan on using your Mongoose models outside of the Express app.  Something like this (note, not using the ACL in this case, though you could if you wanted):

```
app.param('orderId', (req, res, next, id) => {
  Order.findById(id, (err, order) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (order) {
      req.order = order;
      return next();
    }
    const notFound = new Error('Order not found');
    notFound.status = 404;

    return next(notFound);
  });
});

app.put('/api/orders/:orderId', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.order.status !== 'pending') {// or whatever your code setup is
    const notProcessable = new Error('Cannot modify an order in process');
    notProcessable.status = 422;
    return next(notProcessable);
  }

  // handle the modification and save stuff
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. I am very grateful. I would try it out and get back to you on the result. I really appreciate your effort towards helping me. Strange enough it looks very simple.

Comment: I am very grateful for the help although I could not make use of any of the acl I had to write my own to fit into my code. I would still accept the answer

Comment: @SMev you're welcome.  I *did* say it wasn't a great fit for ACL libraries... ;)

Comment: I hope that I am not disturbing. Do you have any idea how this question can be solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857561/insert-new-data-or-update-into-mongodb-through-addtoset-and-arrayfilters-in-mong