# insert new data or update into mongodb through addtoset and arrayfilters in mongoose node.js javascript array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to update a model in mongodb through mongoose but I have not been able to achieve what I wanted.
My goal is to ensure that if there is a matching data with my arrayfilter query then updating should be made else if there is no matching data a new data should be inserted.
This is what I have done so far

```
Model.update({
    'firstArray':{$elemMatch:{
        'item1':'New Disk', 
        'item2':'New records',
        'item3':'New band'
    }}
    },
    {$addToSet:{'firstArray.$[num1].secondArray.$[num2].thirdArray.$[num3].fourthArray':{
            subitem1 : 'Track 1',
            subitem2 : '6 minutes',
            subitem3 : 'The jet move',
            subitem4 : '45000 downloads',
            subitem5 : '1000 likes',
            subitem6 : '200 comments'
        }
    }},
    {arrayFilters:[
        {"num1.item1":'New Disk',
         "num1.item2":'New records',
         "num1.item3":'New band'},
        {"num2.releasedate":'2017-05-03'},
        {"num3.award":'none',
         "num3.fourthArray.subitem1":'Track 1'
         "num3.fourthArray.subitem2":'6 minutes',
         "num3.fourthArray.subitem3":'The jet move'
        }],
        safe: true, upsert:true},
        function (err, updateDetail){
            if(err){}
            else{
            }
        }
    );
```

From the above the subitem1 is Track 1 which exist. I expect the information in the addToSet to update the information in the database.
But if the subitem1 is Track 2 which does not exist then a new data should be inserted into the array.

I have tried modifying the arrayFilters and the query , there were times when a new data was inserted when I expected update but an update was never done at all.

subitem1 to 3 are the only ones that are consistent the others might change hence I need an update based on these array filters

Please how can I achieve this.

I discovered that if I do not include fourthArray in the arrayFilter it insert a completely new item but the update is never done.
But when I include the fourthArray into the arrayFilter no new data is inserted nor is there any update action done.

**UPDATE**

This is a sample document

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bbf975759a97c1094a200b2"), 
    "firstArray" : [
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5bbf975759a97c1094a200b3"), 
            "item1" : "New Disk", 
            "item2" : "New records", 
            "item3" : "New band", 
            "secondArray" : [
                { "_id" : ObjectId("5bd7ef5eca682d1b34ff6b85"), 
          "releasedate" : "2017-05-03", 
          "thirdArray" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId("5bd7ef5eca682d1b34ff6b88"), 
              "award" : "none", 
              "fourthArray" : [ 
                { "subitem1" : 'Track 1', 
                  "subitem2" : '6 minutes', 
                  "subitem3" : "The jet move", 
                  "subitem4" : "35012", //this is for downloads
                  "subitem5" : "715", //this is for likes
                  "subitem6" : 98 //for comments
                } 
            ] },  
            { "_id" : ObjectId("5bd7ef5eca682d1b34ff6b9a"), 
              "award" : "clear sound", 
              "fourthArray" : [ 
                { "subitem1" : 'Track 4', 
                  "subitem2" : '5 minutes', 
                  "subitem3" : "2 nice", 
                  "subitem4" : "75012", //this is for downloads
                  "subitem5" : "1345", //this is for likes
                  "subitem6" : 357 //for comments
                } 
            ]}
          ] 
        } 
      ]}
    ]
}
```

Any h elp would be appreciate.

It is quite surprising that addToSet is only for inserting new record if it does not exist. I thought it was also for modifying already existing data.

If I modify this lines

```
{$addToSet:{'firstArray.$[num1].secondArray.$[num2].thirdArray.$[num3].fourthArray':{
```

and

```
{"num3.award":'none',
     "num3.fourthArray.subitem1":'Track 1'
     "num3.fourthArray.subitem2":'6 minutes',
     "num3.fourthArray.subitem3":'The jet move'
}
```

and change it to

```
{$set:{'firstArray.$[num1].secondArray.$[num2].thirdArray.$[num3].fourthArray.$[num4]':{
```

and

```
{"num3.award":'none'},
{"num4.subitem1":'Track 1'
 "num4.subitem2":'6 minutes',
 "num4.subitem3":'The jet move'
}
```

this would change the data if it finds it there but if there is no matching data, it would not insert a new data which is what I expect

How can I achieve both ends.

Comment: $addToSet will never update any existing objects in an array. Only add, if not previously existant. 

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/: 


> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.

Comment: Can you also please post the relevant part of your Schema or an example document?

Comment: Document has been added to it. Any help would be appreciated